# DLL Load Library Error in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I want to use DLL for `FiscalPrinter`, i placed the `empifis.dll` inside `jre6/bin` folder and called the DLL code in Java program as below,

```
CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("empifis",                              CLibrary.class);
```

It throws the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'empifis': The specified module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:145)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:188)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:123)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:255)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:241)
at org.compiere.pos.Main$CLibrary.<clinit>(Main.java:15)
at org.compiere.pos.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to provide the file extension .dll?

You can btw also put it in the system folder where most of the dlls are stored. Or you add a path to the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Add dll to ClassPath
I think this is what you are [looking for](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html)

Comment: How to add DLL in classpath

Comment: link is given the answer in "looking for"